# T-SQL Issue using lead or lag

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, lag, lead

I have a table that has columns `EVENT_ACTION` and `TIMESTAMP`; in column `EVENT_ACTION` there are two possible values, 225 and 226.

`225` represent the `start_time` and `226` represent the `end_time`; since they are in two different rows I'm trying to use `LAG` or `LEAD` and have some issues.

Here is what I have so far; the column `MRDF` is my unique id:

```
SELECT  
    f.EVENT_ACTION ,
    (f.TIMESTAMP) AS starttime, 
    LEAD(f.TIMESTAMP) OVER (ORDER BY f.MRDF) AS endtime 
FROM  
    dbo.flext f 
WHERE 
    EVENT_ACTION IN (225,226) 
ORDER BY 
    MRDF, EVENT_ACTION
```

This is what I'm getting: it's now getting the next row's timestamp as I thought it would:

[image: Query Results]

I'm getting a null value for my last EVENT_ACTION 255. I'm planing to place this into a temp table and only take EVENT_ACTION 225

As you can see I'm lost :-).

Any help would be appreciated

Mike

Comment: Can you show your source table schema and some sample data please

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `f.TIMESTAMP` as your `ORDER BY` for the `LEAD()`. I think your query should look something more like this:

```
SELECT  
    f.EVENT_ACTION ,
    (f.TIMESTAMP) AS starttime, 
    LEAD(f.TIMESTAMP) OVER (ORDER BY f.TIMESTAMP ASC) AS endtime 
FROM  
    dbo.flext f 
WHERE 
    EVENT_ACTION IN (225,226) 
ORDER BY MRDF, EVENT_ACTION
```

However, this will still leave you with a NULL for the endtime of your last 226 record. So you can add a default value to the `LEAD()` function for this situation. The syntax is:

```
LEAD ( scalar_expression [ ,offset ] , [ default ] )
```

Using this syntax, your `LEAD()` would then become:

```
LEAD(f.TIMESTAMP, 1, GETDATE()) OVER (ORDER BY f.TIMESTAMP ASC) AS endtime
```

You can replace the `GETDATE()` with whatever you'd want the default value to be when there is no leading record.